# How do I rebind a combobox in winforms?[duplicated]

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a Winforms application and a combobox has it's datasource set to a List when the form loads. The data displays fine in the combobox.

Then after a user clicks a button I want to create a new  List and assign that  List as the datasource for the combobox.

The problem is that after setting the datasource to be the new  List the items in the combobox don't change. Here is the code I'm using.

```
    var newPersonList=new List<Person>(){//...};//Person has a property named 'Name'
    dlCustomer.DataSource = newPersonsList
    dlCustomer.DisplayMember = "Name"
    dlCustomer.Refresh()
```

**Does anyone know how to make the correct data be displayed in the combobox the second time I assign new data source for it**?

Comment: .DataSource = personsList should be enough.
What is the type of personsList? Are you sure it is actually populated?

Comment: Clear your combobox item before binding

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the items and then set the DataSource  as below

```
dlCustomer.Items.Clear();
dlCustomer.DataSource = newPersonsList;
dlCustomer.DisplayMember = "Name";
```